# Doxygen ignores show line starting with # in a code section

Tags: doxygen

In my documentation, I create custom pages containing bash code snippets like the following one.

```
@code{.sh}
# Deletes the repository mydir
rm -r mydir
# Another comment.
@endcode

Output:
rm -r mydir
```

The `#` is used to write comments in bash. However, the lines beginning with `#` are not shown in the output. It seems as if any line starting with whitespace plus `#` is completely ignored.

I would like to know why. Is there another way to make doxygen not ignore a line starting with `#` within a code snippet?

My current workaround is to remove the line feed and put the comment on the same line as the `@code`. But this works for the very first line only.

```
@code{.sh}# Deletes the repository mydir
rm -r mydir
# Another comment.
@endcode

Output:
# Deletes the repository mydir    
rm -r mydir
```

**EDIT**

I have identified the issue. It also occurs with doxygen 1.9.8. The problem is a `/*/`, which corrupts all the subsequent parsing.

```
This is the content of Example.dox
/**
@page example Example Page

@code{.sh}
# Code example with comment shown in output
mycodesnippet1
@endcode

What happens in this line? `path/toany/*/dir/`.

Examples: 
@code{.sh}
# Code example with comment missing in output
mycodesnippet2
@endcode
*/
```

The line contains a `*/` which ends the @page. If the path is `path/toany*/dir/`, then parsing indeed ends here and the second code example is entirely omitted. However, `/*/` seems to be parsed as an opening block comment `/*` and a single slash `/`, so parsing continues beyond this point. But the comment lines starting with `#` are omitted. Does anybody understand this?

My problem now reduces to: How can I write paths in doxygen containing `*/` or `/*/` without confusing the parser?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What happens when you use instead of `{.sh}` `{.unparsed}`?

Comment: doxygen 1.8.13, same behavior with `{.unparsed}`.

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.13 is old, from December 26 2016, the current doxygen version is 1.9.8 please check with this version.